# How could an object float/levitate in a spherical shell

Tags: science-fiction, physics

Would it be theoretically possible for an object to float or levitate in a spherical shell, and retain its position in relation to the ground whilst the shell moves around it, and if so, how would this state be attained?

Comment: What object, what's the shell made of? (Check out the [levitating frog](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.5.010033/full/), you'll see that that Nobel Prize has already been given, much to the annoyance of amphibian-rights activists).

Comment: How large is this thing.. you want a pilot inside ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start with a [hoverball](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08QTP3MLT).

[image: hoverball]

Maybe you want to make it out of a balloon, so it floats?  This hoverball has GPS and so if requested, it stays put as regards its coordinates like good drones do.

It is inside a sphere.  Maybe it is a big sphere you use as a hoverball hangar?  Maybe you have built a [tensegrity sphere!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Nine_(sphere))  In any case, it is a sphere.  You can drive it around or float it around like a dirigible, or perhaps cruise beneath the waves.

The GPS Hoverball inside this sphere does not know what its sphere is doing.  It does know its GPS coordinates and it strives to stay where it is.

Answer (score 1):

### It's already been done. You're looking for magnetic locking using rotating magnets.

Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5FyFvgxUhE&t=407s), which explains the phenomenon in greater detail. In short: magnets are attracted to only one end of another magnet but repelled by the other. Knowing this, rotating the magnets out of sync makes them hover in place, because they can't reposition themselves and end up stuck. They end up magnetically locked without a liquid hydrogen cooled superconductor. However it needs to be constantly rotating to levitate, so while it can be done at normal temperature levels it does requires a constant power supply.

Hopefully this was of some help. Good day to you.